# Bootstrap4 Collapse toggle

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm trying to style collapse toggle on it clicked and expect that there is a toggle class when collapse is show. But the actual logic in bootstrap4, for example:

`<button data-toggle="collapse">Button</button>
    <div class="collapse">Collapse Content</div>`

1. first click, collapse will show and button classname will not be change.
2. click again, a new classname `collapsed` added to button toggle.
3. click again, classname `collapsed` will be removed from button toggle.

How can I style button toggle to different style when collased content is show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#collapseExample').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
   $('#myBtn').removeClass('btn-success');
   $('#myBtn').addClass('btn-primary');
});

$('#collapseExample').on('show.bs.collapse ', function () {
   $('#myBtn').removeClass('btn-primary');
   $('#myBtn').addClass('btn-success');
})

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


 <button id="myBtn" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Button 
  </button>

<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-body">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
  </div>
</div>
```